# Move right container inside left navbar (responsive)

Tags: html, css

I have the below design done for my website.

[image]

`div 1`, `div 2`, `div 3` are wrapped up in a `<navbar>` container.

On responsive design for mobile I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

So I want to move the `div 4` inside the `<navbar>` container above `div 2`. What's the best and clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use "Order" Property.

```
.parent-div {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.div-1 {
    order: 1;
}
.div-2 {
    order: 2;
}
.div-3 {
    order: 3;
}
.div-4 {
    order: 4;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .div-1 {
        order: 1;
    }
    .div-2 {
        order: 3;
    }
    .div-3 {
        order: 4;
    }
    .div-4 {
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is I need to move .div-4 inside <navbar> which contains the other divs.  How do i do that